# Format a picture object

Tags: excel, vba, object, format

I have a object which I can select and move about using the following code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes.Range(Array("test")).Select
```

Followed by whatever method needs to be preformed. I am now trying to format this object so that it has no fill and no lines but cannot figure out how to do this. I have tried recording macros and searching online but cant find anything that applies to this object.

Comment: what type of object are you working with? Is it a Shape? Declare a `Dim shp as Shape` and use the intelli-sense to get to the Fill property etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it after a million different attempts!

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes.Range(Array("test"))
.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
.Line.Visible = msoFalse
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with an individual shape, I see no reason to use `Shapes.Range(Array("test"))`, try to work maybe with the individual shape, and refer to the documentation for available properties, like `.Fill`:

Shape object reference:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff847149(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff847149%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Shape `.Fill` reference:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838181(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838181%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

etc.

```
Sub Test()
Dim shp as Shape
Set shp = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("test")

shp.Fill.Visible = msoFalse

'etc...
End Sub
```